# What are these connections - External rotor motor

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I have an external rotor motor with the following connections.

[image]

The power is quite clear. I assume F/R is forward and reverse but I am not sure ACC, DEC, and MFG. I assume they are some sort of motor control but Google and ChatGPT are not being very helpful.

Comment: guessing accelerate, decelerate, motor frame ground ... what exactly is the device?

Comment: It is from a laser printer. I want to try and get it going in another project.

Answer (score 0):

l 8P terminal, two positive wire, two negative wire, FR is the direction wire

l ACC is the start line, connect the negative pole to start, disconnect it to stop, DEC is the PWM speed control line, the frequency is about 500Hz~2kHz